# The command returned a non-zero code: 127

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build the below Dockerfile, but it keeps failing on `RUN ocp-indent --help` saying `ocp-indent: not found The command '/bin/sh -c ocp-indent --help' returned a non-zero code: 127`

```
FROM ocaml/opam

WORKDIR /workdir

RUN opam init --auto-setup
RUN opam install --yes ocp-indent
RUN ocp-indent --help

ENTRYPOINT ["ocp-indent"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

I bashed into the image that ran before it via `docker run -it <image id> bash -il` and ran `ocp-indent --help` and it ran fine.  Not sure why it's failing, thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure why it'd be necessary if `run` works, but have you tried specifying a full path to `ocp-indent`?

Comment: How? `Run <path to ocp-indent.exe>`?

Comment: Yeah. It's probably in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Comment: It's actually in `home/opam/.opam/4.04.2/bin`, which is also present in `echo $PATH`.  Let me try putting that in the Dockerfile and see what happens.

Comment: OK that worked, but that doesn't make sense nor can I use that reliably since ocaml/opam will update their versions, making 4.04.2 not work. But that helps from a troubleshooting perspective.  Any idea why Run would fail there?

Comment: for anybody that runs into this, I was trying to use apt-get on an alpine image, and apt* doesnt exist since its only for Ubuntu. Alpine use apk instead of apt-get

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a PATH related issue and profile. When you use `sh -c` or `bash -c` the profile files are not loaded. But when you use `bash -lc` it means load the profile and also execute the command. Now your profile may have the necessary path setup to run this command.

**Edit-1**

So the issue with the original answer was that it cannot work. When we had

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-lc", "ocp-indent"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

It finally translates to `/bin/bash -lc ocp-indent --help` while for it to work we need `/bin/bash -lc "ocp-indent --help"`. This cannot be done by directly by using command in entrypoint. So we need to make a new `entrypoint.sh` file

```
#!/bin/sh -l
ocp-indent "$@"
```

Make sure to `chmod +x entrypoint.sh` on host. And update the Dockerfile to below

```
FROM ocaml/opam

WORKDIR /workdir

RUN opam init --auto-setup
RUN opam install --yes ocp-indent
SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-lc"]
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

After build and run it works

```
$ docker run f76dda33092a
NAME
       ocp-indent - Automatic indentation of OCaml source files

SYNOPSIS
```

**Original answer**

You can easily test the difference between both using below commands

```
docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/sh" <image id> env
docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/sh -l" <image id> env
docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash" <image id> env
docker run -it --entrypoint "/bin/bash -l" <image id> env
```

Now either you bash has correct path by default or it will only come when you use the `-l` flag. In that case you can change the default shell of your docker image to below

```
FROM ocaml/opam

WORKDIR /workdir

RUN opam init --auto-setup
RUN opam install --yes ocp-indent
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-lc"]
RUN ocp-indent --help

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-lc", "ocp-indent"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Comment: The `SHELL` line looks like it needs to go above the `RUN` lines though. Thanks.

Comment: Which image should I run those `docker run` commands against?  Putting the SHELL above WORKDIR and building it created the image, but doesn't run in a container due to this error:  `Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"ocp-indent\": executable file not found in $PATH"`

Comment: @user1795832, my bad you should have just used `ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-lc", "ocp-indent"]`. Updated the code in answer

Comment: But the build still fails because the `ENTRYPOINT` step is after all of the RUN steps.  Doesn't `SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-lc"]` still need to be there above the RUN steps?

Comment: @user1795832, yes i didn't realize you were using the command in run also

Comment: This shouldn't be running as a shell script though, should be as an executable.  Once the image is running in a container it should be as easy as `ocp-indent --version` from a terminal.  The `SHELL` line fixes building the Dockerfile into an image, but it still won't run due to that executable file not found in path error.

Comment: @user1795832, realized the mistake. updated the answer

Comment: This technically works, but I don't think this will work the way intended to.  I'm going to accept your original answer as that fixes the question I posed initially.  I'll post a separate question addressing the `docker run` issues.  Thanks for your help

Comment: For reference the new question is here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408740/docker-image-run-results-in-executable-not-found-in-path

Comment: You need to make this `ocp-indent "$@"`, with the quotes. Otherwise your arguments will get string-split and glob-expanded before being passed through.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, updated the answer. Thanks for the help!