# Docker image run results in executable not found in path

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is a continuation of a previous question: 
 [The command returned a non-zero code: 127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46374737/the-command-returned-a-non-zero-code-127).  I'm trying to build and run the below Dockerfile for use by others.  My original issue was the build failed due to profiles not loading (wonderfully answered in the above question), now I'm trying to get it to run properly.

Here is the Dockerfile I'm currently at, which builds fine now that it has a SHELL step (forgot that the idea is to also use whalebrew in the end for even easier install).

```
FROM ocaml/opam

SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-lc"]
LABEL io.whalebrew.name 'ocp-indent'
LABEL io.whalebrew.config.working_dir '/workdir'
WORKDIR /workdir

RUN opam init --auto-setup
RUN opam install --yes ocp-indent
RUN ocp-indent --help

ENTRYPOINT ["ocp-indent"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

I then run it via `docker run -it <image id>`, but I get an error: `Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"ocp-indent\": executable file not found in $PATH".` As mentioned in the answer of the other question, could create a .sh file for the entrypoint, run a chmod script, and make a few other changes to Dockerfile.

Ultimately I'm trying to make it as easy as possible on people wanting to install this. e.g.:  `whalebrew install <name>` followed by `ocp-indent --version` should output its version just like that.  They shouldn't have to do anything more.

I'm still learning Docker as I go, their docs are actually pretty good but difficult to troubleshoot issues.

Comment: Have you tried providing absolute path in the entrypoint? Like `/workdir/ocp-indent`

Comment: I'm not following the specific issues you're having with the entrypoint.sh script. What are the various commands you want to be able to run with what syntax?

Comment: @BMitch Ultimately don't want to force users to run more scripts.  As I understand it, they would have to run a chmod script themselves after they install it, or is that not correct?

Comment: You would chmod your entrypoint.sh in your Dockerfile, or even in your code repo if you're running builds on a system that supports that. There's no need for a user to change the image that comes out of your build.

Comment: @user1795832, the solution i posted in previous question did chmod for the build to happen and avoid additional RUN statement to just chmod inside the build. The user will not need to have any file with them, then image would work as it is

Comment: Thanks @BMitch and Tarun Lalwani.

Comment: Sorry, still having trouble with this. The image was built and published to docker, however when I install it via whalebrew, the commands don't do anything.

Comment: If I run `docker run unibeautify/ocp-indent --version` it outputs the version, but the intent is to leave the docker run part out of it, so just `ocp-indent --version` is needed.

Comment: @BMitch forgot to tag you. I would also tag this under `whalebrew` but there isn't a tag for that nor do I have the reputation to create one.  More info on whalebrew to understand what I'm trying to do:  https://github.com/bfirsh/whalebrew#how-it-works

Comment: I think I've narrowed it down to the `-t` which allocates a pseudo-TTY.  With `docker run -it ocp-indent --version` or even just `-t`, nothing happens.  But `docker run -i ocp-indent --version` works, and shows the version number.  `-t` is how whalebrew runs docker images.  So now the question is, why doesn't it do anything when the `-t` is passed?