# Why would Docker image not run with -t included?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

A hopefully last question on this Docker image, continuing on from [Docker image run results in executable not found in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46408740/docker-image-run-results-in-executable-not-found-in-path).  I'm finding that the Docker image does not run when `-t` is included in the `run` command.  So `docker run -it <image> --version` simply exits without an output. However if I remove the `-it` or even just remove the `-t`, it outputs the version as I expect.

My question is, why doesn't it work with `-t` to use a pseudo-tty?  Would the ocaml/opam image being used somehow prevent that from happening?

Dockerfile

```
FROM ocaml/opam

SHELL ["/bin/sh", "-lc"]
LABEL io.whalebrew.name 'ocp-indent'
LABEL io.whalebrew.config.working_dir '/workdir'
WORKDIR /workdir

RUN opam init --auto-setup
RUN opam install --yes ocp-indent
RUN ocp-indent --help

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh -l
ocp-indent "$@"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `sh` login option (`sh -l`) then output with the pseudo tty (`docker run -t`) will work as normal.

This appears to be a global issue for that Dockerfile. Running any binary command after loading the login profiles will react the same:

```
→ docker run -ti --entrypoint=/bin/sh 4ead19c50fc7 -c "tail -2 /etc/passwd"
messagebus:x:104:107::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
opam:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/opam:/bin/bash

→ docker run -ti --entrypoint=/bin/sh 4ead19c50fc7 -lc "tail -2 /etc/passwd"
→
```

Whereas in a container running the base `ocaml/opam` image, commands using a login shell are ok:

```
→ docker run ocaml/opam sh -lc "tail -2 /etc/passwd"
messagebus:x:104:107::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
opam:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/opam:/bin/bash

→ docker run ocaml/opam sh -c "tail -2 /etc/passwd"
messagebus:x:104:107::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
opam:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/opam:/bin/bash
```

The `opam init --auto-setup` step probably overrides some Docker specifics in the image. You can remove it from the `Dockerfile` and use the specific path for the command. I'm not very familiar ocaml so not sure if this is "the way" to do it.

```
FROM ocaml/opam

LABEL io.whalebrew.name 'ocp-indent'
LABEL io.whalebrew.config.working_dir '/workdir'
WORKDIR /workdir

RUN set -uex; \
    opam install -vv --yes ocp-indent; \
    /home/opam/.opam/4.04.2/bin/ocp-indent --help

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/opam/.opam/4.04.2/bin/ocp-indent"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for that explanation.  I was hesitant to change the entrypoint because at some point ocaml/opam will update and use 4.05.0 and I don't want to change the Dockerfile everytime that changes.  One thing I tried, and maybe you can tell me if it was a bad idea, was changing `#!/bin/sh -l` to `#!/bin/bash -l`.  That seemed to fix it.

Comment: Generally I'd try and keep all config for an app visible in the Dockerfile or supporting files rather than in random profile files that `-l` sources. Other language package managers like `npm` or `composer` can create a generic `bin` link to a specific version as a part of the install, maybe `opam` has an option to do that?  but if bash works... it works :)